# EmberJS 1.0 HasMany Relationship Create Record

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to gather the canonical answer for how to create a record in EmberJS 1.0 for a hasMany relationship.

There sees to be a ton of outdated documentation and I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 2):

The following has been working for me since ED 1.0 beta 2:

```
var child = this.get('store').createRecord('child', {
   name: 'New Child',
   parent: parent
};
child.save();

parent.get('children').addObject(child);
// My backend automatically adds the inverse of relationships when saving     
// the child, so I don't need to save the parent separately
```

where `parent` is the parent object. You may need to specify `needs: ['parent']` in your controller and then get the parent using `var parent = this.get('controllers.parent.content');`, where 'parent' is the name of your parent object.